# Sturm-Liouville Eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider Sturm-Liouville endpoint problems of the form $y''+\lambda y=0$ with the usual endpoint conditions.  $c_1y(a)+c_2y'(a)=0$, $d_1y(b)+d_2y'(b)=0$. Here $(c_1,c_2) \neq \vec{0}$ and $(d_1,d_2) \neq \vec{0}$.  We know that the eigenvalues form a discrete sequence tending to infinity.

My question is, can we arrange the boundary conditions $a,b,c's,d's$ to get an arbitrary number of negative eigenvalues?  For example, can we arrange to get precisely two negative eigenvalues?

If I want eigenvalues $\lambda=-2,-1$, can I arrange for this?

Comment: Two are possible. No more than two, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Would you have a reference or argument?

Comment: See Section 4.3, Problem 8 in [Partial Differential Equations](http://www.amazon.com/Partial-Differential-Equations-Walter-Strauss/dp/0470054565/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1380419873&sr=1-1&keywords=strauss+partial+differential+equations)

Comment: Thanks Artem; that certainly answers my question!